# Compile slf4j in Unix

Tags: java, unix, jar, slf4j

I have a Java program that uses `slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar` and `slf4j-simple-1.7.10.jar`. I have tried to compile it in my Unix shell like so:

```
javac -cp "$CLASSPATH:.:slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar:slf4j-simple-1.7.10.jar" Test.java
```

Running `java Test` results in this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        at SystemCommandExecutor.<clinit>(SystemCommandExecutor.java:13)
        at Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
        ... 2 more
```

I am able to run the program in Windows with the two jar dependencies, so I don't believe I need any extra jars. Perhaps I am issuing the wrong command to compile in Unix as I am fairly unfamiliar with the syntax.

Comment: You need the Jars on the classpath at runtime as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't create a pom.xml for compile it with a maven dependency?

In that case you should include the package for the main class:

javac -classpath external.jar com/yourpackage/yourMainClass.java

Also check your syntax for the slf4j inclusion.